# Sweetalert delay popup from opening

Tags: javascript, alert, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to delay a SweetAlert popup to not display for a few seconds once it has been triggered.

e.g. User performs action on webpage to trigger SweetAlert, but instead of displaying instantly, it wait 2 seconds and then displays. - I've been researching various ways to do this, but no luck...I think maybe `setTimeout` is needed?

Here is my SweetAlert function which is working so far:

```
if( response == 10 ){
    swal({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'YOUR BALANCED BOX IS FULL',
      text: 'Youve added the recommended amount of items for your plan!',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      showCancelButton: true,
      cancelButtonText: "Modify Selection",
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#61ce70',
      confirmButtonText: "Proceed To Cart",
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            window.location = "/basket/";
        }
    }) 
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: will setTimeout work for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed you can use setTimeout to achieve this easily, i set up a simple snippet so you can try it out!

```js
// When button gets clicked.
$("#button").click(() => {
 // Instantely change it's text to loading..
 $("#button").text("Loading!");
  // Wait 2kms then change the text to Done!
 setTimeout(() => {
   $("#button").text("Done!");
  }, 2000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Event</button>
```

-Leo

Comment: Thanks Leo! Helped me find the answer - Have marked yours as correct and added the specific solution below.

Answer (score 2):

**SPECIFIC SWEETALERT 2 ANSWER:**

Above code logic answer from Leo is correct. Am sharing the final version with SweetAlert 2 with `setTimeout` as a function added to delay the popup from opening.

The `setTimeout` function wraps around the entire SweetAlert 2 function and the timer is set at the bottom of the end of the function (in this case to 3000).

Hope this helps anyone looking to do the same!

```
    setTimeout(function(){swal({
  type: 'success',
  title: 'YOUR BALANCED BOX IS FULL',
  text: 'Youve added the recommended amount of items for your plan!',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  showCancelButton: true,
  cancelButtonText: "Modify Selection",
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  showConfirmButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#61ce70',
  confirmButtonText: "Proceed To Cart",
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    window.location = "/basket/";
  }
})},3000);
```